# How to deal with fixed max number of posts a user can make within a time period?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, database-design

Sorry for titlegore.

Users can have at most 3 active posts, and each post is active for 48 hours.

I was thinking about just putting `active_post_{1/2/3}_id` and `active_post_{1/2/3}_expires_at` on the `users` table, but wondering if there is a better way to handle something like this.

Comment: I would just build the logic into the insert query itself

Comment: How would I do the conditional check for 3 active posts?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store only the timestamp of the post and use middle-tier logic to restrict the number of active posts to three.

If you have a table like so:

```
create table posts (
  id int generated always as identity,
  user_id int not null references users(id),
  created_at timestamptz not null,
  post_text text not null
);
```

You can get the number of active posts with this query and disable the user's ability to create a new post if the result is more than three.

```
select count(*) 
  from posts
 where user_id = ?
   and created_at > now() - interval '48 hours';
```

This could be defeated by a determined attacker through multiple active sessions in your application, but if that is a concern, then I would use the same logic to restrict visible posts to only three per user.  When pulling the list of posts to display:

```
with rnums as (
  select user_id, created_at, post_text, 
         row_number() over (partition by user_id
                                order by created_at desc) as rn
    from posts
   where created_at > now() - interval '48 hours'
)
select user_id, created_at, post_text
  from rnums
 where rn <= 3
 order by user_id, created_at desc;
```

If you want to use PostgreSQL to enforce this constraint, then you would need to bring triggers into the mix.